# spawn command issue in Expect Script

Tags: expect

I am having some trouble with my expect script.

I dont know why spawn command doesn`t perform any action , it just echo out the same text ..

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn apt-get install expect
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh 10.10.80.1
```

it just prints out the same text when I execute it .. using ./test.sh , here is the result

```
spawn apt-get install expect
```

AND

```
spawn ssh 10.10.80.1
```

could anyone help?

Comment: In light of the one answer, I think this is a legitimate `expect` question, suggesting re-open.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the *spawn*'ed process to complete (exit):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn apt-get install expect
expect eof
```

Without `expect eof`, `expect` would exit afer it *spawn*ed the `apt-get` process. When `expect` exits it'll terminate all running *spawn*ed processes so `apt-get` would be killed immediately after it's *spawn*ed.

> it just echo out the same text

By default the `spawn` would echo the command. You can use `spawn -noecho` to disable this.